# replace values that cannot be converted to integer to zero python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using python3.8, pandas 1.1.4

MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5, 6], "b":["01", "02", 1, "//N", None, np.nan]})
```

I want to convert `column b` to integer so that "01" = 1 (they should be same), "02"=2, etc... while replacing values that cannot be converted to integer to 0.

Current method:

```
c = []
for val in df["b"].unique():
    try:
        int(val)
    except:
        c.append(val)
        pass
    
df["b"] = df["b"].replace(c, 0)
df["b"] = df["b"].astype(int)
```

outputting (it's desired output):

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   1
3   4   0
4   5   0
5   6   0
```

Even though this works, I'm searching for more efficient and readable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) + [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to replace NaN with `0` and `downcast` from `float` to `int`:

```
df['b'] = pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='int')
```

Or convert to `int` with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['b'] = pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

`df`:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  1
3  4  0
4  5  0
5  6  0
```

Comment: from documentation, it says when downcast parameter is set to 'integer' it convert to smallest signed int dtype. So I've tried `df['b'] = pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer').fillna(0)` however this returns float datatype. Do you know why?

Comment: Smallest type _possible_. If there is a string "3.45" in `b` the smallest possible type is `float`. downcast will not make a dtype change that would result in a data loss. Additionally, `NaN` is a float so downcast will not work with `to_numeric` if coercing errors to `NaN` "As this behaviour is separate from the core conversion to numeric values, any errors raised during the downcasting will be surfaced regardless of the value of the ‘errors’ input.". This is why I added the `astype(int)` option in case you need to force the reduction from float to int.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `np.where`:

```
x = df['b'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)')
df['b'] = np.where(x.notna(), x.astype(float), 0)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  2  2.0
2  3  1.0
3  4  0.0
4  5  0.0
5  6  0.0
```